# FrameLayout vs Relative Layout for Image overlays

Tags: android, android-framelayout, android-relativelayout

Is there an advantage to using the FrameLayout over the RelativeLayout for image overlays? Would it make sense to use one over the other if I plan to have the background image static , and the foreground image dragged and scaled by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you want to have a view hierarchy as flat as possible meaning the less nested view you have the better.

The logic inside a RelativeLayout is more complex than the one in FrameLayout. Therefore performances might be slightly better with a FrameLayout but I wouldn't count on this too much. However if using a RelativeLayout over a FrameLayout reduces your number of nested layouts, go for it!

Comment: Good answer, this is how I would break it down as well.

Comment: I basically want to have a picture of a persons face , then drag and drop smaller images on top of it, glasses, lips etc. Then eventually combine and save them as one image. To accomplish this I think I need 2 imageviews on top of each other, but I am not quite sure if it would be better or make a difference if I had them in a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout. I guess I should try them both.

Comment: If what you described are the only views you'll have inside your layout, then you are not using any of the features of a RelativeLayout (positioning views relatively to one or many siblings). In this case use a FrameLayout which will be exactly the same for your case.

Comment: Awesome! If you could set the answer as solved, that would be great